# Save figure with python and display with php

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to use a PHP script in a Localhost to plot the result of some mathematical process and I'm having some issues.

My idea is to upload a text file with php; save it on a folder; process this file
with python and save a figure on the same folder; and then display the saved figure with
php.

Anyone can help me ?

1)
The data is loaded uploaded with php using the following code:

```
  <?php

    define("UPLOAD_DIR",realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/uploads/' );
    $name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
    chmod(realpath(dirname(__DIR__)).'/uploads', 0755);
    chmod(realpath(dirname(__DIR__)).'/uploads/'.$name, 0755);

     $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],
                        UPLOAD_DIR . $name);

?>
```

Then I get:

Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myPhpScripts/upload1.php on line 7 
And the file was not saved.

2) 
I want to do some signal processing with Python and display a saved picture with php.

```
>>>     #!/usr/bin/env python
>>>     import numpy as np
>>>     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>>     x = np.random.randn(100)
>>>     y = np.fft.fft(y)
>>>     plt.plot(y)
>>>     plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Then I compile my python script

```
$sudo chmod +x myFft.py
```

When I run the python code from terminal it saves the test.png on the current folder:

```
$./myFft.py
```

but when I call this script with:

```
<?php

    $omega = system('./myFft.py');

?>
```

nothing happens

So I changed my python script to:

```
>>>     #!/usr/bin/env python
>>>     import numpy as np
>>>     x = np.random.randn(100)
>>>     y = np.fft.fft(x)
>>>     print y
```

Once again I compile the python script

```
$sudo chmod +x myFft.py
```

And now I can store the fft result to a php variable with:

```
<?php
    $omega = system('./myFft.py', $pyVal);
?>
```

The $pyVAl variable stores the fft result.

Why I can save a figure running the python script on the terminal but not within php script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1) You're trying to chmod a file which doesn't exist yet:

```
chmod(realpath(dirname(__DIR__)).'/uploads/'.$name, 0755);
                                             ^^^^^--- you haven't moved the upload yet
move_uploaded_file(...);
```

The ordering should be

```
move_uploaded_file(...);
chmod(...);
```

As well, note that directly using the `['name']` parameter like that opens your system to a total remote compromise. `['name']` is USER provided data, and can including pathing data.  If someone hacks their upload to say (say) `../../../../../etc/passwd`, there goes your system.

2)  How are you running the PHP script? As a command line, or via the webserver? Remember that those are two totally different environments, with different `uid`/`gid` - the python script as executed under the webserver may not have permission to write out that file, whereas when you run it yourself at the command line, it's running as you and does.

Comment: Many thanks!
I tried to change the code order but I'm still getting the same WARNING messages. I'm running the PHP script at     http://localhost/myPhpScripts/upload1.php

If there's the possibility that my Python code, executed from PHP, do not have the permission, how can I set my PHP to run a Python script to save a figure?